# Krishna the Vajra among weapons

Tags: krishna

Before the Kurukshetra war, while giving the Gita knowledge to Arjuna, Krishna said that he is the Indra among Devas, and the Vajra among the weapons, and so on.

My question is: why did not he mention about his own Sudarshan Chakra? Does it mean that his Chakra is less powerful than Vajra??